# Passing the DLL path from C++ to Fortran

Tags: c++, dll

I am trying to get the path of the DLL I am in, into a local variable of type:

```
  char dbankpath[] = "c:\\temp";
```

I need this end type due to the requirement of the Fortran function I am calling.

From various threads here I believe the DLL path can be obtained in DLLMain by:

```
  wstring DLLPathAndName;
  wstring DLLPath;
  
  void setdllpath(wstring);
  
  BOOL APIENTRY DllMain( HMODULE hModule, 
                         DWORD   ul_reason_for_call, 
                         LPVOID  lpReserved )
    {
    switch (ul_reason_for_call)
      {
      case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
      case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
      case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
      case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
        break;
  
      const int BUFSIZE = 4096;
      wchar_t buffer[BUFSIZE];
  
      if (::GetModuleFileNameW(hModule, buffer, BUFSIZE - 1) <= 0) { return TRUE; }
  
      DLLPathAndName = buffer;
  
      size_t found = DLLPathAndName.find_last_of(L"/\\");
      DLLPath = DLLPathAndName.substr(0, found);
      setdllpath(DLLPath);
      break;
      }
  
    return TRUE;
    }
```

So now I have the DLL path in a wstring. I then pass this into another function in my main code:

```
  std::wstring g_DLLPath[256];

  void setdllpath(std::wstring DLLPath) {
    g_DLLPath = DLLPath;
    }
```

which copies it into a global variable g_DLLPath.

Now I need to get that into the char dbankpath[], for which I wrote another function (obtained from another thread here):

```
  #include <cstdlib>
  
  void copywstringtochar(std::wstring wStr, char *buffer) {
  
    const wchar_t *input = wStr.c_str();
  
  // Count required buffer size (plus one for null-terminator).
    size_t size = (wcslen(input) + 1) * sizeof(wchar_t);
  
    #ifdef __STDC_LIB_EXT1__
        // wcstombs_s is only guaranteed to be available if __STDC_LIB_EXT1__ is defined
        size_t convertedSize;
        std::wcstombs_s(&convertedSize, buffer, size, input, size);
    #else
        std::wcstombs(buffer, input, size);
    #endif
  
    }
```

which I call by:

```
   copywstringtochar(g_DLLPath,&commandfile);
```

However this will not compile.  I can't help thinking I'm making this way too complicated, in Fortran it is 2 or 3 lines of code.

Is there a simple way of getting the DLL path into char dbankpath[] ?

Comment: `std::wstring g_DLLPath[256];` -- You declared an array of 256 strings, and not one string that has 256 characters.

Comment: *In Fortran it is 2 or 3 lines of code.* -- Probably Fortran is doing something similar under the hood that your code is attempting to do -- it is just hidden from you.

Comment: If it will not compile then you should include the error message.

Comment: Why not call `GetModuleFileNameA` instead of `GetModuleFileNameW` and just write the path directly into `dbankpath`? Why go through all these intermediate steps?

Comment: BTW `char dbankpath[] = "c:\\temp"` is not correct since you do not have enough space in the array. Perhaps you meant `char dbankpath[256];` or something similar.

Comment: I did not think it was useful to show the error messages as I knew I was on the wrong track.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For reference, I post my solution here.

```
 char dbankpath[_MAX_PATH];
 
 void setdllpath(char* dbankpath);
 
 BOOL APIENTRY DllMain( HMODULE hModule, 
                        DWORD   ul_reason_for_call, 
                        LPVOID  lpReserved )
   {
   switch (ul_reason_for_call)
     {
     case DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH:
       GetModuleFileNameA(hModule, dbankpath, std::size(dbankpath));
       for (int i = strlen(dbankpath)-1; i>=0; i--) {
         if(dbankpath[i] == '\x5c') {
           dbankpath[i] = '\0';
           break;
           }
         }
       setdllpath(dbankpath);
       break;
     case DLL_THREAD_ATTACH:
     case DLL_THREAD_DETACH:
     case DLL_PROCESS_DETACH:
       break;
     }
 
   return TRUE;
   }
```

setdllpath is a function which sets the DLL path in my own class:

```
 char g_DLLPath[_MAX_PATH];
 void setdllpath(char* DLLPath) {
   strcpy(g_DLLPath,DLLPath);
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

The simple approach is to call `GetModuleFileNameA` and write the path directly into the global array. Something like

```
GetModuleFileNameA(hModule, dbankpath, std::size(dbankpath))
```

with `dbankpath` declared something like this

```
char dbankpath[_MAX_PATH];
```

As you said, just 2 or 3 lines of code.

Comment: Thanks! I got this to compile and link successfully, but I'll need to test it later before I post the Answer.